# MySQL trigger to set salary insert/update limits

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

So I have a table employees and I am trying to ensure that staff cannot earn more than their managers.

Here is my attempt to create a trigger for that

```
create trigger staffsalary before update on employees for each row begin
if ((new.salary < 50000) where staffid < 200000) 
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'A promotion is required
for staff to earn above 50k'; end if; end^^
```

I have also tried to tailor the trigger to say where staffed like '1%' because my staff IDs who are not managers start with 1.

But nothing has worked, and MySQL keeps showing me an error where I have 'where staffID < 200000).

Help or suggestions what alternatives may work would be appreciated!

Comment: @Kevin thanks, but unfortunately does not answer my question at all

Comment: if ((new.salary < 50000) where staffid < 200000)  is clearly wrong, where conditions are not available in if statements see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html change to an and.

Comment: < 50000 conflicts with the message text and why did you abandon the NEW.staffid in favour of staffid (which the trigger doesn't know about).

Comment: I tried that (and instead of where) and the trigger is accepted, but does not actually work properly

Comment: create trigger staffsalary before insert on employees for each row begin if ((new.salary < 50000) and (new.staffid < 200000)) then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'A promotion is required for staff to earn above 50k'; end if; end^^ so this is what I did, still doesn't work

Comment: Yes it does see answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon strange - I copied it, and it still allows me to insert a salary that is too high!

Comment: My guess is you didn't drop the old trigger,

Comment: @P.Salmon ah no, everything worked, I had the wrong sign < instead of > thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> delimiter $$
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> create trigger staffsalary before update on employees for each row begin
    -> if ((new.salary > 50000) and new.emp_no < 5) then
    -> signal sqlstate '45000'
    -> set message_text = 'A promotion is required for staff to earn above 50k';
    -> end if;
    -> end $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> delimiter ;
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select emp_no, salary from employees;
+--------+--------+
| emp_no | salary |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |  20000 |
|      2 |  39500 |
|      3 |  50000 |
|      4 |  19500 |
|      5 |  10000 |
|      6 |  19500 |
|      7 |  40000 |
|      9 |   NULL |
+--------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update employees set salary = 66000 where emp_no = 1;
ERROR 1644 (45000): A promotion is required for staff to earn above 50k
```